# Page indexing problem with Google search console

Tags: javascript, html, google-search-console

Recently, I created my first website and registered at Google search console.
The address is https://www.chemjix.com. However, as I always landed on the insecure http address when entering just [www.chemjix.com](http://www.chemjix.com) in the address bar, I use the index.html to forward to https and directly to the correct language (English or German). After adding the website to Google search console, I got the message for the http that it is not indexed because of "Soft 404 Website" and "Page with redirect".

Is that a problem and does Google therefore rank my website lower or something like that? And what would be the alternative, do I need to get rid of that redirection?

Thanks a lot
celdri

Comment: Isn't clear what do you mean about "I use the index.html to forward to https", but consider using your server's redirect method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use your hosting provider's tools to setup your domain correctly. You should use only https, as these days this is a must have for websites.
Most providers have some kind SSL or integrated the free Let's Encrypt solution for a real free for life SSL.
If you have a working site in https, you may use the hosting provider's own solution (like in Cloudways for example we have a swith) to redirect every URL to https, or you should use .htaccess redirect rules.

You also can additionally take advantage of Cloudflare not just to domain managament and caching, but to setup, and handle and check full SSL route from user to server.

Comment: Thanks, I missed the option, but after your answer, I checked again with my provider and found it.